# Probability of events in a certain order

Tags: probability, statistics

So assume we have $10^6$ lights. The probability of one lighting up is 1 in $10^5$ when we trigger the switch.

The chance of 500 of them lighting up when we trigger the switch would be 1 in ${10^{5*500}} $ = 1 in $10^{2500}$, correct?

Considering the same pool of $10^6$ lights, what is the probability of 500 lights lighting up in a SPECIFIC order after triggering the switch 500 times? The actual order doesn't matter. For example, what's the probability that EXACTLY light nr. 1 lights up before nr.2 before nr.3 .... before nr.500, for example?

Is it higher or lower than the other probability of 1 in 10^2500?
Also could you please post the calculation as well?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Even more important than using mathjax is to give the necessary context , in this case, which probability distribution do we have ? Binomial distribution ?

Comment: Well each light has a $$\frac {1}{10^5}$$ probability of lighting up, that's independent of anything.